# How to constrain the type of the output of a method of an abstract class?

Tags: python-3.x, abstract-class

Say I have an abstract class:

```
class A(metaclass=ABCMeta):

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def a_function(self) -> int:
        return 0
```

I want to constrain the type of the output of `a_function` so that when a class inherits from `A` the output has to be an integer.

My first attempt was to make a decorator for `a_function` of class `A` (see below). But of course it only constrains `A.a_function`

```
def constrain_type(f):
    def decorated(*args, **kwargs):
        output = f(*args, **kwargs)
        class_annotation = f.__annotations__["return"]
        if not issubclass(type(output), class_annotation):
            raise TypeError("this class must return an object inheriting from " +
                            class_annotation.__name__ + " not " + type(output).__name__)

        return output
    return decorated
```

Comment: What do you mean ? This is Python 3.6 code.

Comment: IIRC, Python 3 doesn't use the `__metaclass__` assignment, but rather another way. You should have written `class A(metaclass=ABCMeta)` or something alike.

Comment: Correct. I'm going to edit my post. Thank you

Comment: Good question then. I don't know an answer so I just +1